# Do Something And Continue Class Execution

Tags: javascript, oop, angularjs

I want to add some headers before calling $http's get method. I tried this:

```
$http = $originalHttpMethod;
this.$http = function() {
   //add headers
   return $http
};
$http.get({url:'http://...'});
```

but i get this error:

> TypeError: Object function () {return $http} has no method 'get'.

I want to do this without crash original class.
How can i done this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a service instead of doing anything local. This way you can reuse it much easier across your application.

```
module.factory('$myHttp', ['$http', function($http) {
  //do your stuff
  return $http;
}]);
```

And then inside your controllers, directives or any other services, just include it as a dependency and use it like so:

```
$myHttp.get()
```

Here's some more info about that:

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/10/more-angularjs-magic-to-supercharge-your-webapp.html#you-should-be-using-custom-services

Comment: In your example, the service name would be `myHttp` inside the controller rather than `$myHttp`.

Comment: Right. Fixed. Thanks for picking that up.

Comment: If your service function returns an object, it would be better to use factory() instead of service().  service() is meant for constructor functions.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395686/angularjs-service-in-separate-file/13406613#13406613 for more info if interested.

Comment: Good point. I guess in this situation it's meant to return the modified $http object.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your headers in the [config parameter object](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#Usage) when you call the $http service:

```
configObj = {url:'http://...', headers: { add your headers here}, ... };
$http.get(configObj);
```