# AngularJS service in separate file

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs, project-structure

My app.js contains

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider, $http) {
    ...
}]);
```

Service looks like

```
app.service('MyService', function () {
    addNums = function (text) {
        return text + "123";
    }
});
```

And in contoller I have

```
function adminCtrl ($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.txt = MyService.addNums("abc");
};
```

They are all in separate files. The problem is that I'm getting an error 
`Unknown provider: MyServiceProvider <- MyService`

Looks like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You should use `this.addNums = function (text)` instead of `addNums = function (text)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The provider error can occur if you forgot to tell Angular to load your myApp module.  E.g., do you have this in your index.html file?:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Your service is missing "this.":

```
this.addNums = function(text) {
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/V3EvS/).

---

There seems to be a lot of confusion in the Angular community about when to use service() vs factory(), and how to properly code them.  So, here's my brief tutorial:

The [service() method](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#service) expects a [JavaScript constructor function](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs2.shtml).  Many Angular code examples that use service() contain code that is not a constructor function.  Often, they return an object, which kind of defeats the purpose of using service() —  more about that below.  If an object needs to be created and returned, then factory() can be used instead.  Often, a constructor function is all that is needed, and service() can be used.

The quotes below are from different AngularJS Google Group posts:

> The main difference between using factory() vs service() is that factory()
>   must return an object, while service() doesn't return anything but it
>   must be an object constructor function.
>
> Use factory() if the function you are providing builds the object you
>   want.  I.e., Angular will essentially do
>   obj = myFactory()
>   
>  to get the obj. Use service() if the function you are providing is
>   a constructor for the object you want. I.e.,  Angular will essentially do
>   obj = new myService()
>   
>  to get/instantiate the obj.

So when people use service() and its code "return"s an object, it is kind of a waste because of the way JavaScript "new" works:  "new" will first create a brand new JavaScript object (then do stuff with prototype, then call the function defined by myService(), etc. -- details we don't really care about here), but because the function defined by myService()  returns its own object, "new" does something a bid odd:  it throws away the object is just spent time creating and returns the object that the myService() function created, hence the "waste".

> One of the reasons that service() was introduced was to make it easy
>   to use "classical" OO techniques, such as defining your service as a
>   coffeescript class.

Also, the undocumented naming convention for services seems to be camelCase with first letter lowercased:  e.g., myService.

Comment: Decided to use `factory` after all.

Comment: The fiddle does not show how to define service in a **separate** file as asked in the question.

Comment: *One of the reasons that service() was introduced was to make it easy to use "classical" OO techniques, such as defining your service as a coffeescript class.* This seems to describe `factory()` rather than `service()` as it's when you are using the former you are supposed to construct the object yourself thus you have a chance to use whatever class you want. You write yourself *If an object needs to be **created** and returned, then factory() can be used instead.* (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 2):

You need to return addNums in app.service callback.

```
app.service('MyService', function () {
  addNums = function (text) {
    return text + "123";
  }
  return addNums;
});
```

Now, whenever you use MyService, angular will give you back the addNums function to use.

Therefore, you should use it in your controller like so (note there isn't the addNums call):

```
function adminCtrl ($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.txt = MyService("abc");
};
```

Comment: A service() shouldn't really return anything -- it should define a constructor function (see my answer for more info if interested).

Answer (score 2):

Just as an added clarification on Brian's answer, if you wanted to still have your code call MyService.addNums you could  use the following:

```
app.service('MyService', function() {
    var result = {};
    result.addNums = function (text) {
        return text + "123";
    };

    return result;
});
```

Then you could still use

```
MyService.addNums("abc");
```

if you wanted to do so.